# How to create sqlite database in javascript?

Tags: sqlite

How can I create a database in sqlite from JavaScript?

Comment: If you ask SQLite to open a database file that doesn't exist, when you start creating tables in it, the file will be created. **What specifically is your question?**

Comment: And another question: what platform? iphone? android? normal (win/linux) server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

May this script help you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function createDatabase(){
    try{
     if(window.openDatabase){
             var shortName   =  'db_edentiti';
             var version   =  '1.0';
             var displayName  =  'Edentiti Information';
             var maxSize   =  65536; // in bytes
             db    =  openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize);
                    alert('Sqlite Database created');
         }
    }catch(e){
     alert(e);
    }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Where is this DB located exactly?

Answer (score 1):

For what you want to use sqlite? in firefox you could get extension sqlite manager so there you could create database and tables...but if you are developing on ios you have to create entities in xcode

hope it helps
Wblade

++so I suggest you to use AJAX instead Javascript or php

I find:

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('sqlite:/usr/local/zodiac');$db->beginTransaction();
$q = $db->query("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name = 'zodiac'");if ($q->fetch() === false) {    $db->exec(<<<_SQL_
CREATE TABLE zodiac (
  id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  sign CHAR(11),
  symbol CHAR(13),
  planet CHAR(7),
  element CHAR(5),
  start_month TINYINT,
  start_day TINYINT,
  end_month TINYINT,
  end_day TINYINT,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
)
_SQL_
);    $sql=<<<_SQL_
INSERT INTO zodiac VALUES (1,'Aries','Ram','Mars','fire',3,21,4,19);
INSERT INTO zodiac VALUES (2,'Taurus','Bull','Venus','earth',4,20,5,20);
INSERT INTO zodiac VALUES (3,'Gemini','Twins','Mercury','air',5,21,6,21);
_SQL_;    foreach (explode("\n",trim($sql)) as $q) {
        $db->exec(trim($q));
    }
    $db->commit();
} else {
    $db->rollback();
}
?>
```

Comment: i wan't to create in javascript platform for saving data offline.

Comment: Do you work in Adobe air enviroment?because it is the only enviroment i know which use javascript and sqlite

Answer (score 0):

Hi There are multiple ways to create a db using SQLite, as you know SQLite is very lightweight and very flexible of datastorage, the commands also are very easy to remember.

I am a Windows XP User.

In my system i have extracted the SQLite engine 3.X to **C:\Ronald\Personal\epmc\JavaJ2EE**

u can some Editor like **SQLiteBrowser**, its very nice to work with. no extra framwork needed.

Open a command prompt and point to the SQLite engine.

In my case it was **C:\Ronald\Personal\epmc\JavaJ2EE**

give the following command to create a DB

```
          sqlite3.exe TestDB.db;
```

Once u give this automatically the database file will be created in the particular location.
Then start creating tables like what you have done in Oracle or MySQL.

Thanks
**Ronald Reagan Nathan**

Answer (score -1):

You can try the SQLite administrator:

http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/

it is a good tool to have around anyway.